# Subscript array of structs

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

Given I have array of stucts like this:

`let array = [Struct(key: "a", value: 1), Struct(key: "b", value:2)]`

How can I subscript the array with the key?

`array["b"]` would be nice, but as expected, it doesn't work.

*Edit:* The reason I'm not using dictionary, is I need to preserve the order of items.

Comment: make it array of dictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is syntactic sugar around your solution, @AdamBardon.

You can extend Array to allow you to subscript it directly.  Under the covers it is just using the same `first(where:)` call:

```
protocol HasKey {
    var key: String { get }
}

struct Struct: HasKey {
    var key: String
    var value: Int
}

extension Array where Element: HasKey {
    subscript(str: String) -> Element? {
        return self.first(where: { $0.key == str })
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let array = [Struct(key: "a", value: 1), Struct(key: "b", value:2)]

if let x = array["a"] {
    print(x)
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Struct(key: "a", value: 1)
> ```

Using the `protocol` allows you to easily extend this functionality to any `class` or `struct` that has a `key: String` property by having them adopt the `HasKey` property:

```
extension SomeOtherClass: HasKey { }
```

---

You can also accomplish it without the `protocol` by checking if `Element == Struct`:

```
extension Array where Element == Struct {
    subscript(str: String) -> Element? {
        return self.first(where: { $0.key == str })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for! :) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can make the dictionary of dictionaries like below code:

```
let myDictionaryOfDictionaries : [String : [String : String]] =
["Apples" : ["Colour" : "Red", "Type" : "Granny Smith"],
 "Oranges" : ["Colour" : "Orange", "Type" : "Seville"]]

print(myDictionaryOfDictionaries["Apples"] ?? "")
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I've just edited my question, the reason I'm not using dictionary, is I need to preserve the order of items.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a dictionary. Arrays are designed to access elements by their index and not by a property of the element. Indexes also have to be integers.

Dictionaries on the other hand are key-value pairs, so using a Dictionary seems to perfect for your use case.
`let structs = ["a":Struct(key:"a",value:1),"b":Struct(key:"b",value:2)]`
`structs["b"]` returns the struct with key "b".

Comment: Yes, dictionary was my first choice, however I need to preserve the order

Comment: In most cases it is easier to get around the issue of a Dictionary being unordered than trying to access elements of an Array with a non integer index. What are you exactly trying to do for which you need ordering?

Comment: The context is too complex to be explained here, but anyway I have an alternative. I'll provide it as answer as it solves my problem. Nonetheless thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not the exact way how I imagined the solution, but it's a good alternative which solves my problem.*

I got what I needed using this:
`array.first(where: { $0.key == "b" })`